# TestNG Error Cannot find class in classpath when running from command line

Tags: testng

I'm trying to run testng via command line and I have following things in classpath:

testng jar, jar of compiled test case file.
testng.xml points to appropriate class in the hierarchy.

in maven all works fine but when trying to run it from command line:

```
java -classpath .;C:/dev/farm-controller/tests/testng-6.8.jar org.testng.TestNG "C:/dev/farm-controller/tests/testng.xml"
```

i get the following error:

> [TestNG] [Error] Cannot find class in classpath:
>   com.company.rest.FarmControllerTest

what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Where r u runnin ur tests from..which dir?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a jar, then you should be putting * instead of . In your classpath or the name of the jar explicitly.